# Why object const can be changed after definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constants

In JavaScript:

```
const a = 6;
a = 2; // Error

const o = {};
o = 7; // Error
o.a = 5; // Good. Why?

const o = {a:1};
o.a = 2; // Good. Why?
```

I found people sometimes define a const object but later change its value. Why a const can be changed after its definition?

Comment: changing a property of an object is not changing the object itself

Comment: You can't *reassign* a const-you can't change its reference. You can *the underlying thing it's referencing*, like adding object properties. You're looking to freeze the object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable declared with `const` means *one thing*: the *standalone variable name* cannot be reassigned with `=` later.

In contrast, `o.a = 5;` is not reassigning the variable name - it's mutating the content of the object, but it's not changing what the `o` variable points to in memory.

To prevent *reassignment* of a variable name, use `const`. To prevent *mutation* of an object is something entirely different - for that, you'd need something like [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or manipulate objects using [immutable-js](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js).

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, `a` is `const` and cannot be reassigned. In the second and third, the object `o` is `const` so that object cannot be assigned another value, but its properties are not `const`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

> The `const` **declaration** creates a read-only reference to a value. It does **not** mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

Answer (score 1):

`const` variables aren't enforced to be immutable.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. **The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared**.

Emphasis mine.

`o.a = 5` isn't reassigning `o`; it's reassigning a property in `o`.

Answer (score 1):

For adding more information from the other answers, if you want to define a constant object property. You can try these ways:

```js
const o = {
  get a() {
    return 1;
  }
};

o.a = 2;

// 1
console.log(o.a);

const o2 = {};

Object.defineProperty(o2, 'a', {
  value: 1,
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

o2.a = 2;

// 1
console.log(o2.a);
```