# Manipulating a const array

Tags: javascript

Why JS allows mutating const arrays?

e.g.

```
const a = 5
a = 6 //throws error

const arr = [1,2,3]
arr[2] = 4 // no error
```

Why is it allowed to mutate a const array when it should throw an error as in the first case?

**Also how do I ensure that my array remains completely immutable?**

Comment: `const` prevents an assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why object const can be changed after definition in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516721/why-object-const-can-be-changed-after-definition-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **allowed to add, delete or mutate const array in JS** because `arr` variable **stores the memory reference** and not the values.

So even if you manipulate the values at that memory location you are not really changing the reference to the memory and hence the variable remains `const`.

The only thing that is not allowed is re-assigning the array `arr = []`
which essentially means changing the memory reference the arr variable stores.

As @Nina stated **any kind of assignment to const variables is not allowed**.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

arr[2] = 4 //this is fine as memory reference is still the same
arr[3] = 3

console.log(arr)
arr = [] //throws error
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: btw, it has nothing to do with an array, just a new assignment (whatever type) to the variable is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar value in Javascript is stored by value. For example:

```
let a = "foo" <--- a is linked to the value "foo"
let b = "foo" <--- b is also linked to the value "foo"
```

Objects and arrays are stored by reference. For example:

```
const arr = [1,2,3] <--- arr is linked to a unique address in memory that references 1, 2, and 3
```

When an array or object is mutated, the address in memory doesn't need to change:

```
arr.push(4) <-- arr is now [1,2,3,4], but its address in memory doesn't need to change, it's still just an array that references 1, 2, 3, and now 4
```